# Storing data locally or just using ajax on mobile devices? - appcelerator

Tags: ios, database, mobile, titanium, local-storage

Currently I'm building a few mobile apps (currently on iOS but later on Android)that retrieve information via ajax calls (returning JSON) from a Ruby on Rails application. This obviously applies to other applications as well that are using another source to return the JSON data.

The main question is WHEN to store the data and when to just use ajax calls to retrieve it. Currently, my apps do not store a single thing locally and instead require ajax calls for all data. I think for this example we can use the Twitter mobile app, which is one a lot of people are familiar with and has a lot of functionality that I'm wondering how they do it (more logically than technically).

Questions:

**1)** When you log in the first thing you see is a list of all of the items in your stream. That list is available offline. Does that mean that when you originally signed in, Twitter already went and pulled all of your last X (100?) stream items into a local database and then future views just pull it from there?

**2)** If you then put your phone on airplane mode (or just shut off mobile data) and click one of those tweets, it opens up the tweet page with all of that data. So now, it looks like they aren't pulling that information in via individually each time you visit a tweet page (which is what my app currently does and takes some time to load that data in and create the views). Does it make sense that they are probably just using the same information that they pulled in when creating your stream items?

**3)** Users. Is it better practice to (when viewing a users "profile" page for example) store a users data locally and then refresh on future visits, or just do pull in all of the data via ajax each time? In theory each requires an ajax call...

I think those are my main questions for now. If anyone has any thoughts on any of those things (or any other insights into mobile storage) that would be great! If anyone needs screenshots of anything I referenced please let me know and I'd be happy to get those for you.

Currently using:

Titanium Appcelerator for iOS
Ruby on Rails for Backend and remote storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok firstly there is a difference between local storage and device cache.

Mobile phones cache a lot of data so that it doesn't have to be requested each time using up your data plans. Its the same idea when you open a page on safari, go to home screen and go back into safari its still there. This wasn't saved locally its just been cached by IOS.

When you should use local storage is when the data never changes, using twitter as an example like you have, on first start up it downloads your current activity, if one of those contains a link then it will generate a new request, if you have turned off cellular data and still been able to click a link, this is not because twitter has stored it locally but because IOS has cached it temporarily to avoid downloading multiple times. twitter may very well store some of you activity locally, but at least from what I've seen it stores a maximum limit of them starting with most recent, it downloads the rest frequently.

generally speaking if the data is based on the web its fine to use ajax calls, that is what most do, local storage is when the data is only created / viewed on the device (like an app for taking down notes). If you wish to provide local storage so that someone can view there activity offline, great but this is a feature not a requirement.

Most people would only start thinking about this if users frequently request the same data over and over and its not going to change often, then you would need to develop a last modified system, where you send an ajax call to see is there anything new, if not read from local. If the data is dynamic and subject to change often, stick with the ajax calls

Comment: Simon, thanks for that! Really great information. I think that this sentence "_If you wish to provide local storage so that someone can view there activity offline, great but this is a feature not a requirement._" really hits the nail on the head. What I'll do for now (and in the future) is rely solely on ajax calls until the app is built entirely, and then see if there is a way to use local storage to help speed it up at all. You're right, with dynamically created content updated frequently it's probably a good idea to just leave the data on the remote server for the most part. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, yes unless it makes no sense to use Ajax calls its definitely something to decide after the app is built as a maintenance / upgrade task. Good luck with future apps